# change bitmap image to pixels array

Tags: android

I have to change it through android as in java I have

```
byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

(here image is BufferedImage), but

```
int[] pixels;
image.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width , height );
```

(Here imgae is bitmap image)
returns the pixels value not as java.

Comment: int width = bitmap.getWidth();
int height = bitmap.getHeight();
int[] pixels = new int[width*height];
bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height); //try this

Comment: Use Hiren dabhi lines.It work in android too..+1 to hiren

Comment: this has been solve by like this
  int[] pix1=new int[w*h];
  image.getPixels(pix1, 0, w, 0, 0, w , h ); 
  pixels= new byte[pix1.length*3];
  for (int i = 0; i < pix1.length; i++) {
   int td = pix1[i];
   int tind = i * 3;
   pixels[tind++] = (byte) ((td >> 0) & 0xFF);
   pixels[tind++] = (byte) ((td >> 8) & 0xFF);
   pixels[tind++] = (byte) ((td >> 16) & 0xFF);
   
  }

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
Bitmap bmp = intent.getExtras().get("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: This result would be compressed, he asked for a method corresponding to standard java #getPixels(..).